# How can I get my iPhone photos to sync?

Tags: backup, sync, itunes, iphone, photos

I occasionally have trouble synchronizing my ±20k photo album to my iPhone, where (new) photo albums aren't added, or only show up as empty albums. Does anyone else have this problem and more importantly, have a structural solution to this?

I experience the following symptoms:

- iTunes does not sync (new) photos properly
- iPod Photo Cache directory only contains ±1MB "Photo Database" file, as opposed to GBs of thumbnails as expected when syncing does work
- "Error: the iPhone could not be synced because the sync session failed to finish"
- Empty photo albums (i.e. 0 photos in albums) on iPhone while storage indicates presence of photo albums
- No albums in iPhone Photos app, while storage (in iTunes and iPhone) indicates significant storage used by photos

What I've tried with only partial success, and without understanding why this helps:

- Create new empty photo directory and move photo directories here
- Use "Transfer Purchases from iPhone" [source1](http://osx-sos.com/not-synced-sync-session-failed-finish/) [source2](https://discussions.apple.com/message/30359263#30359263)
- Delete iPhone backup
- Delete iPod Photo Cache

Hope somebody can shed some light on this!

Comment: I had dreadful problems trying to synchronise an iPad with the Windows version of iTunes, so much so that I removed iTunes altogether. I now mount the iPad as an external drive in Linux and update the files direct using `cp -ua ...`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn’t an actual question it’s an answer to some unasked question.